# Query existence of GLSL extension in SPIR-V shader

Tags: glsl, vulkan, spir-v

In regular GLSL I can do something like this to conditionally enable a GLSL extension:

```
#if defined(GL_ARB_shader_viewport_layer_array)
    #extension GL_ARB_shader_viewport_layer_array : enable
    // Some other stuff here
#endif
```

My question is, how can I achieve the same in SPIR-V using the glslang library? I'm assuming I'll need to compile multiple versions of the same shader to achieve this? Or is there a way to conditionalize SPIR-V on the existence of an extension without generating two binaries for two versions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In regular GLSL I can do something like this to conditionally enable a GLSL extension:

First of all, no you can't. Not every OpenGL extension ot GLSL exposes such a #define. For example, nowhere in the [GL_ARB_shader_viewport_layer_array extension](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/ARB/ARB_shader_viewport_layer_array.txt) will you find that define to be specified to be there. By contrast, the [GL_ARB_shader_group_vote extension](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/ARB/ARB_shader_group_vote.txt) does specify a `#define`.

Second, even if the extension provides a #define, that still won't work. Because the #define is only exposed if you *activate* the extension with a #extension directive. So your example will never get shader_viewport_layer_array working.

If you want an [extension to be conditionally present](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Core_Language_(GLSL)#Extensions), you use `#extension NAME : enable`. If the implementation doesn't support the extension, you won't get it (you'll get a warning in the shader log file). You *detect* whether or not the extension is active with the #define discussed earlier.

As for how to do that with SPIR-V... you *don't*. SPIR-V is an intermediate language, not a high-level one. The expectation is that the SPIR-V is written against a particular version of the host environment, including extensions. If you want to conditionally support some extensions and not others, you have to generate multiple SPIR-V shaders for those combinations of extensions that you intend to support.

SPIR-V has no equivalent to #ifdef, again because it is an intermediate language.

Comment: Fair enough, and thanks for the heads up that my code is undefined behaviour (although in practice it does work on Windows, Mac and Linux on thousands of customer machines). I guess my big problem with SPIR-V right now is that we have a few specializations and this just adds to it. Basically I now need to generate 3x the shaders (which would be fine if I wasn't generating 100k versions already).